# Convert 1D vector to 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I got a compiling error when using std::copy to convert a 1D vector to a 2D vector.

```
int main() 
{  
    std::vector< std::vector<float> > v2D(10, std::vector<float>(10, 0.0)); 
    std::vector<float> v1D(100, 0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        v1D.push_back(i);

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        std::copy(v1D.begin() + j * 10, v1D.begin() + (j + 1) * 10, std::back_inserter(v2D[j].begin()));
    }
}
```

Would you please help solve this proplem? Thank you.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::back_inserter` takes a container, not an iterator. Change `std::back_inserter(v2D[j].begin())` to `std::back_inserter(v2D[j])`. Note that this will be calling `.push_back()` on the `std::vector<float>` at `v2D[j]`, so you probably also want to change `std::vector< std::vector<float> > v2D(10, std::vector<float>(10, 0.0));` to `std::vector< std::vector<float> > v2D(10);`.

Alternatively, you can change `std::back_inserter(v2D[j].begin())` to `v2D[j].begin()`. This works because `std::copy` wants an output iterator, and `std::vector<>::iterator` behaves as one when there are a sufficient number of elements in the `vector<>` to overwrite. And this way, your current initialization of `v2D` is already ideal.

---

**EDIT**: Someone else said this in a separate answer then deleted it, so I'll say it on their behalf because it's definitely noteworthy: because you initialize `v1D` with 100 elements, the [1..100] digits you then `push_back` are *appended* to the initial 100 elements (which all have your specified value of 0) rather than overwriting them. You should change `std::vector<float> v1D(100, 0.0);` to `std::vector<float> v1D;` to get the behavior you apparently want (or `std::vector<float> v1D; v1D.reserve(100);` if you're really being pedantic about efficiency).